# CSS shape-outside with text blocks

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

We've seen text border a circle like this:

[image]

But I need to have text blocks align around a circle, similar to this:

[image]

I've tried different ways to block the text (internal spans, negative margins, display block, etc). But I am not having any luck. I don't totally understand shape-outside, but I get the feeling it forces the shape on a line by line basis, completely ignoring blocks.

I'd like to avoid absolutely positing the items with a static pixel value. I am hoping to solve this programmatically rather than setting each value manually. I'd prefer to use just CSS, if possible.

Any brilliant ideas?

Comment: are those those text nodes known size, or each will vary?

Comment: They vary now, but I could modify the requirements to be identical. What are your thoughts?

Comment: If they have fixed heights and positions, you could get away with a custom-made stair shaped polygon as the clip-path... but at that time absolute positioning or simple nth-child left margins would make much more sense.

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rgmmuf6/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can have a similar output without using `shape-outside` but with some **skew** tranformation then you can adjust the degree if skewing and/or some margin.

```css
body {
 max-width:580px;
}
.circle {
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 25px 5px 0;
  float: left;
}
.first {
  transform:skew(20deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
.first > p {
  transform:skew(-20deg);
}
.second {
  transform:skew(-20deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.second > p {
  transform:skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="first">
  <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem </p>
</div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem </p>
<div class="second">
  <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce the result with a simple solution.

```
.your-circle-shape-outside {  
  float: left;
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.your-text-in-divs {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Markup

```
<div class="your-circle-shape-outside"></div>

<div class="your-text-in-divs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, vel corporis. In delectus repellat tempora nihil autem soluta enim eum assumenda. Totam quisquam excepturi laborum! Consequatur ab repellat est recusandae.</div>
<div class="your-text-in-divs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, vel corporis. In delectus repellat tempora nihil autem soluta enim eum assumenda. Totam quisquam excepturi laborum! Consequatur ab repellat est recusandae.</div>
<div class="your-text-in-divs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, vel corporis. In delectus repellat tempora nihil autem soluta enim eum assumenda. Totam quisquam excepturi laborum! Consequatur ab repellat est recusandae.</div>
<div class="your-text-in-divs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, vel corporis. In delectus repellat tempora nihil autem soluta enim eum assumenda. Totam quisquam excepturi laborum! Consequatur ab repellat est recusandae.</div>
<div class="your-text-in-divs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, vel corporis. In delectus repellat tempora nihil autem soluta enim eum assumenda. Totam quisquam excepturi laborum! Consequatur ab repellat est recusandae.</div>
```

Adding display flex to the elements that surround the circle will align the text vertically to the left of each block. The margin bottom can be what suits

Comment: I should have left a code example, my divs look like this:  
`<div>     
<b>Foo</b>    
<br />  
<span>lorem ipsum dolor</span>  
</div>`

Comment: Ok, if you can't change this markup add to your outer div 

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;

This should align your elements vertically to the left also

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the *positioning* and `pre` *element*, which defines *preformatted text* and preserves both *spaces* and *line breaks*. This way you can easily place the *content* wherever you want:

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}

pre {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 75%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <pre>
    test test
    test test

       test test
       test test

        test test
        test test

       test test
       test test

    test test
    test test
  </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to simulate the circle with a stairs like shape as to be seen in this example:

[image]

This shape can be created using the `clip-path: polygon()` property of CSS. Now the text will float according to the shape of the stairs.

#### Advantages

- multiple lines are always aligned to a vertical line without the use of transformations
- the various text blocks don't have to be handled one by one
- the size of the stairs shape is easy adjustable due to percentage values of the single polygon points

#### Limits

- The number of lines of a single block can't vary since the size of the stairs itself has to be adopted in the polygon itself

#### Working example

```css
.curve {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -40px;
  background: darkgreen;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.text-shape {
  height: 250px;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* <- set the last value to != 0 to see the stairs shape */
  shape-outside: polygon(0 100%, 33% 100%, 33% 80%, 80% 80%, 80% 60%, 100% 60%, 100% 40%, 80% 40%, 80% 20%, 33% 20%, 33% 0, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 33% 100%, 33% 80%, 80% 80%, 80% 60%, 100% 60%, 100% 40%, 80% 40%, 80% 20%, 33% 20%, 33% 0, 0 0);
}

p {
  padding-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="curve"></div>
<div class="text-shape"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit amet</p>
```